# Unhandled rejection RangeError: Using transaction with a client that is in monitor mode does not work due to faulty return values of Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Seems like a valid question for SO,

I'm executing a multi atomic transaction using the library node-redis for Node.JS and in my log results from my IBM Bluemix, I receive the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection RangeError: Using transaction with a client that is in monitor mode does not work due to faulty return values of Redis.
```

Now here's the interesting part, the bug is being pinpointed to line 255 within my script:

```
 /* Code Above */
 //
 //
 //
 new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{


   [LINE 255] client.multi().hget(practitioner, "texted").hget(practitioner, "replied")
                .execAsync().then((replies)=>{
                  console.log(replies);
                  var _replied = replies[1],
                      _texted = replies[0];
                  if (_replied && _texted){
                    retrievalSuccess = `Practitioner ${practitioner} has sent a message to the NOK participant
                                        \s ${contact.fname} ${contact.lname} at ${TimeStamper()},
                                        \s participant returned SMS of OK
                                        \s, closing..."`;
                    console.info(retrievalSuccess);
                    auditFile.message += "\n"+retrievalSuccess;

               /* rest of the code */
```

My route wasn't throwing any errors **UNTIL** I added this snippet of code to the callback

```
 client.monitor((err, res)=>{
   console.log("Entering monitoring mode.", res);
 });

  client.on("monitor", (time, args, raw_reply)=>{
    console.log(time + ": " + args); // 1458910076.446514:['set', 'foo', 'bar']
  });
```

Is the monitor feature unable to process the two of those transactions on the server? I'm still able to execute `.exec()` commits before this statement, I'm unsure if the `execAsync` is the underlying reason as to why I can't receive a log statement and it disrupts the runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Redis-Node:

> The monitor client may not fire any other commands than quit after
>   activating monitor. You have to open a new client and then fire the
>   commands with that one instead. The monitor client is going to receive
>   everything that is happening with the other client.